# TeX template for Communications in Algebra

Tags: templates, journal

I need a tex template for the journal ''Communications in Algebra'' but they don't supply any templates on their web page. Can anyone help me to find a template that I can use for submitting a manuscript to the journal?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The journal "Communications in Algebra" is part of the Taylor & Francis group of journals. The journal's website states that LaTeX is an acceptable type of input format. (The other is MSWord.) You should contact the journal -- via the link https://authorservices.taylorandfrancis.com/contact/ -- and choose "Word or LaTeX templates" from the drop-down menu to send them a query. They may not have a ready-made template, but they may provide some general guidelines as to acceptable engines (pdftex, xetex, or luatex), document classes, and LaTeX packages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question should be posed to the journal's publisher

Answer (score 1):

Is [Communications-in-Algebra Template](https://typeset.io/formats/taylor-and-francis/communications-in-algebra/f66e2bd2fef2f5e6223b3148af08fd45) what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you should state explicitly that the template you've spotted is for typesetting MS Word documents according to the "Communications in Algebra" formatting guidelines. Given that the title of the OP's posting contains the word "TeX", the OP may not be able to make use of a template that doesn't work with a tex- or latex-formatted input file.